# worker process in IIS shared hosting

Tags: iis, .net-3.5, process, worker

Can anyone tell me, is there a way to run a process in IIS shared hosting service.

Suppose, the scenario is like "I want to send emails to a list of email id's after everywhere 3 hrs", so the challenge here is the process should not be invoked by a HTTP link. It should be automatic.

I think we can do this by IIS worker processes.

Also this all will be happening on a shared server(like GoDaddy) in IIS7, .NET 3.5

Please anyone give me a direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write and run this as a Windows service, assuming you have access to install a service.

You could run a background worker thread from your asp.net code-behind but the problem is that IIS will terminate the thread after it is idle for a relatively short period of time.  I tried going this route, trying to geocode a list of addresses (800+, from a SharePoint list) and IIS kept timing out my thread and stopping it.  We ended up going with adding events to the SharePoint list that would geocode when the item was changed/added to the list.

One other option you could look into is using Windows Workflow API, it was designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: so this means..i can do this, if i have purchase a VPS account with godaddy.... ???

Comment: could be,I don't really know about what kind of accounts godaddy has.  I would ask their tech support or something first, before you spend the $, just to be sure that account type supports it.

Comment: that's fine...godaddy is not the only one. But, i know that hosting people give you full desktop access of your VPS. So, i think the windows service way, would be the best in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked ages ago, but for what it's worth - I ended up using [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to handle my long running tasks in my ASP app.

You can easily configure it for shared hosting and then for a dedicated server if you can scale up / out according to your needs.

It's super easy to use, just follow the doc step by step.

Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: Yes, hangfire rocks for long tasks, I highly recommand it too!